# How do you make a public class to retrieve user info

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a class with some methods to get user's info. I'm making it like libraries.

For example, the current logged in user has some data in firestore. Say I want to retrieve his username.

This is placed in the same activity where I want to retrieve the username.

```
String currentUserUsername;

private String getUserUsername(DocumentReference currentUserDocument) {

    currentUserDocument.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {

            currentUserUsername = documentSnapshot.getString("username");

        }
    });

    return currentUserUsername;

}
```

And I'm calling `getUserUsername(currentUserDocument)` after activity ***onCreate*** so I can use `currentUserUsername` anywhere I want in the code. But the problem is that I'm doing this in many activities. How can I make it like a public class like those libraries?

Comment: want to store `documentSnapshot.getString("username");` one time?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No, I want to call it when needed.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That's my question. How do I do it?